Google OAuth2 additional access screen after google changed its UI
I have a spring boot app with react. I use spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client to authorize by Google. My application.properties file contains all necessary data:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientId=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientSecret=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=email, profile

In google cloud I specified these scopes as well.
In react I redirect to ${backendUrl}/oauth2/authorization/google to log in.
Everything has been working correctly, I could authorize just by selecting my google account, however, since Google has changed its log in UI I'm getting extra screen about getting approving additional access by the App, every time I want to authorize. Currently I access only email and profile scope, and I have this specified in Google API. So, I do not know, what additional access is requested every time I authorize.
google additional auth screen (SCREENSHOT)
I have no idea why is it happening. I hasn't changed anything.
I tried looking into google docs, but nothing has changed so didn't find any answer there.
I also followed spring docs https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2 but as well, didn't find any clue.

What is the issue exactly the user just needs to authorize access now

I'm getting extra screen "APP wants additional access" every time I authorize. I only want to access email and profile scope, and I specified it in google API as well. So I don't know which additional access is requested.

what access is it asking for the that you dont want it to?

It does not specify the additional access that is requesting, just please see the screenshot attached to the question. As I said, I specified scope for email, and profile - these are obligatory for the app and user has accepted them during first auth attempt. However, as you can see, google is requesting additional access every time user wants to authorize again. It's annoying, because user thinks that my app collects more data about him during subsequent logins.

I don't see anything out of the ordinary on the screen shot.   It looks like the standard consent screen, but you do have a lot blacked out.  If they are asking for new access then your probably sending a refresh token that doesn't contain all the scopes that are needed.    Delete the refresh token request a new one so that you have a fresh one with full access and i see if that doesn't fix it.  it may be the openid scope is missing.
